# eslint "Unexpected property on console object was called (no-restricted-syntax)" on console.debug

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, nomachine-nx

When I use `console.debug("some log")` VSC shows an eslint error telling me

```
Unexpected property on console object was called (no-restricted-syntax)
```

I don't fully get how this [no-restricted-syntax](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-syntax#options) works or rather where I find the AST selector  that restricts console.debug.
I am using NX. And in my eslintrc.json file I see that the plugin `@nrwl/nx` is used. Still I don't know where to find the specific rule.

I tried to set `"no-restricted-syntax": "warn"` but that did not change anything.

My goal is to either set the rules to only produce warnings instead of errors or better, to understand where I can really just change this behavior for console.debug.

Comment: hm... "no-restricted-syntax" only shows up once in a search of the repo's contents, and doesn't touch console.debug: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Anrwl%2Fnx%20%22no-restricted-syntax%22&type=code. would need to look levels deeper at what its configs extend. eslint:recommended [doesn't](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/main/packages/js/src/configs/eslint-recommended.js) touch it either.

Comment: neither does typescript-eslint touch it: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/src/configs/recommended.ts https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/src/configs/eslint-recommended.ts. if anyone wants to dig: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin/src/configs

Comment: Are you also in an Angular project? If you are, it's likely because of @angular-eslint which comes in from your project's `.eslintrc.json` -> `plugin:@nrwl/nx/angular` ->`plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended--extra`

https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/issues/1003

Answer (score 1):

I'm making an assumption that you are in an Angular project like me.

If you look at your Angular project's `.eslintrc.json`, you'll see that it extends `@nrwl/nx/angular` which can conditionally include `@angular-eslint/recommended--extra` which contains a rule config for `no-restricted-syntax` to disable calls to `console`.

You can disable `no-restriced-syntax` inside of your project level `.eslintrc.json` file with `"no-restricted-syntax": "off"` or a different config if you need it. You will not be able to do this at the top level `.eslintrc.json` since the rule is being applied currently in the extensions at the project level.

An issue was made in the @angular-eslint github (https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/issues/1003) that seems to infer that this rule was introduced in Angular 13 and that it is removed as of Angular 16, so upgrading might also be an option for you.

Hope that helps.